# How to make sure that every element in a list is greater than .05?

Tags: r

I have the outputs of a dunn.test in a data frame, and for example, in age.results[1,1], there is a list

```
[1] 0.43032565 0.49113535 0.46824512 0.02847439 0.02312762 0.12649953
```

If I want to print "yes" if all of them are greater than .05, how would I do so? 
I initially thought of counting the number that were less than .05, and if it was greater than 0, then I would write another function to print "no". However, if I try

```
sum(age.results[1,1]<.05)
Error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

How can I fix this code to print either "yes" if everything in this particular list is greater than .05 or "no" if even one value is less than .05?

Comment: `desiredresult <- age.results[1,1] > .05` or `any(desiredresult <- age.results[1,1] > .05)`...not sure which one you wanted

Comment: Or use `cat(if (min(x) > .05) "yes" else "no", "\n")`..?

Comment: Sorry just noticed a horrible typo in my above comment `desiredresult <- any(age.results[1,1] > .05)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:
`sum(sapply(results[1,1], function(x) x<.05))>0`

If all of them are greater than .05, it will return `FALSE`, otherwise `TRUE`. You can add an ifelse wrapper around the result to return your own string.

Answer (score 4):

how about?

```
all(results[1,1] > .05)
```

Comment: Very nice!  Wrap that in an `ifelse` to make it print "yes" or "no" and this is by far the simplest answer

Comment: not an `ifelse()`, an `if`: `cat(if (all(results[1,1]>0.05)) "yes" else "no")`

Comment: I get the same error: 
    Error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

Answer (score 0):

```
vec <- c(0.43032565, 0.49113535, 0.46824512, 0.02847439, 0.02312762, 0.12649953)

mean(vec > 0.05) == 1
[1] FALSE
```

also works if `vec` is a list rather than vector, as your question implies

```
mean(as.list(vec) > 0.05) == 1
[1] FALSE
```

So to actually answer your question fully,

```
print(ifelse(mean(vec > 0.05) == 1, 'yes', 'no'))
[1] "no"
```